# Does anybody know what the $current_screen ->id for customizer.php is?

Tags: filters, actions

I searched high and low & tried a bunch of different things but I still wasn't able to add inline css to the customizer.php page.

I usually employ page id `$current_screen ->id === " "` for this type of thing but can't find the page id for customizer.php.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're looking to check if you're in the Customizer, you can use is_customize_preview()

Comment: How would this be applied? 'if (is_customize_preview()) {
    <style>etc.
}' Is that the correct implementation here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen),

> This function is defined on most admin pages, but not all. Thus there
>   are cases where is_admin() will return true, but attempting to call
>   get_current_screen() will result in a fatal error because it is not
>   defined. One known example is wp-admin/customize.php.

Comment: Ah so does that mean it isn't possible then to add inline css to the customize.php page?